# Auto Merge when committing only package.json

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

We have some protected branches in our repository, and everything that needs to be merged to these branches should be done by a maintainer, basic stuff i guess.

Now we are looking for a way to "auto merge" when the MR only contains changes in the package.json file and nothing else.
Is that even possible? Does anyone know how to do that?

We're using the GitLab Community Edition 14.8.2